# how to perform different actions for the done button and the video player finish method of embedded youtube webview in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new to iPhone. Please help me in solving this issue:

I have embedded YouTube webview in Iphone. My problem is when clicking the done button of YouTube I want  to call a class and when the video finishes playing an different class should be called. Can anybody help me on identifying what are the methods called on click of done button and finish of YouTube player in iPhone?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the video is played in UIWebView then you can access when the video is played and when Done button is pressed using the following code along with the code you have used to load url in webview

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoPlayStarted:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
//For Done Button
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoPlayFinished:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
```

And it can be accessed through

```
BOOL isVideoInFullScreenMode;//Temperory added here.. must be in .h file or at teh top if required
-(void)videoPlayStarted:(NSNotification *)notification{
//Your stuff here
   isVideoInFullScreenMode = YES;
}

-(void)videoPlayFinished:(NSNotification *)notification{
    //Your stuffs here
    isVideoInFullScreenMode = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are in a UIWebView, so the done button isn't related to your application: pressing the button will never call your application.

The only method you have are from [UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006951) and they are:

- webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
- webViewDidStartLoad:
- webViewDidFinishLoad:
- webView:didFailLoadWithError:

If you have to know when player finish, I suggest you to try this class: [LBYouTubeView](https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView), it will play youtube video on your player component, so you can use Player delegate's method to to do what you asked for.